# How sort multidimensional array considering only index[0] of each subarray?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How sort multidimensional array considering only index[0] of each subarray ?

I have this array:

```
 var arr= [
 [13538, 6.4,'mese1'],
 [41308, 9.5,'mesi6'],
 [53656, 8.1,'anno1'],
 [271203, 8.3,'anni5']
];

var even= arr;
var magn= arr;
```

and i would to have `even` and `magn` in output like this:

Sort desc by index[0]

```
var even= [
 [271203, 8.3,'anni5'],
 [53656, 8.1,'anno1'],
 [41308, 9.5,'mesi6'],
 [13538, 6.4,'mese1']
];
```

Sort desc by index[1]

```
var magn= [
 [41308, 9.5,'mesi6'],
 [271203, 8.3,'anni5'],
 [53656, 8.1,'anno1'],
 [13538, 6.4,'mese1']
];
```

I tried this code but doesn't work correctly:

```
console.log(even.sort(ordine_decrescente_eventi));
console.log(magn.sort(ordine_decrescente_magnitudo));

//ordino un array in maniera decrescente
function ordine_decrescente_eventi(a,b) {
    return b[0] - a[0];
}   

function ordine_decrescente_magnitudo(a,b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
}
```

This is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/szoe32xb/

I hope you can help me and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in these lines:

```
var even= arr;
var magn= arr;
```

Array assignment creates reference not copy, so in your case you need to change your assignments to:

```
var even= arr.slice(0);
var magn= arr.slice(0);
```

```js
var arr= [
    [13538, 6.4,'mese1'],
    [41308, 9.5,'mesi6'],
    [53656, 8.1,'anno1'],
    [271203, 8.3,'anni5']
];


var even= arr.slice(0);
var magn= arr.slice(0);


console.log(even.sort((a,b) => b[0] - a[0]));
console.log(magn.sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1]));
```

Comment: wtf.... i didn't know the Array assignment creates reference not copy. Grazie ! :)

Comment: @Borja It's a pleasure to read italian. Hence: grazie a te o prego.